# Amazon SNS, how to handle GCM's Canonical IDs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

How to handle GCM Canonical IDs using Amazon SNS?

The method publish(PublishRequest publishRequest) returns

"PublishResult" which has only Message Id's

Answer (score 1):

Amazon is suppose to handle these scenario for you. Read about token management.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqaXXOOxEUY